# How can I filter Flux with state?

Tags: project-reactor

I'd like to apply `filter` on my `Flux` based on a state calculated from previous values.  However, it is recommended to avoid using state in operators according to [the javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html)

> Note that using state in the java.util.function / lambdas used within Flux operators should be avoided, as these may be shared between several Subscribers.

For example, `Flux#distinct` filters items that appears earlier.  How can we implement our own version of `distinct`?

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to my question. [`Flux#distinct`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) can take a `Supplier` which provides initial state and a `BiPredicate` which performs "distinct" check, so we can store arbitrary state in the store and decide whether to keep each element.

Following code shows how to keep the first 3 elements of each mod2 group without changing the order.

```
// Get first 3 elements per mod 2.
Flux<Integer> first3PerMod2 =
    Flux.fromIterable(ImmutableList.of(9, 3, 7, 4, 5, 10, 6, 8, 2, 1))
        .distinct(
            // Group by mod2
            num -> num % 2,
            // Counter to store how many elements have been processed for each group.
            () -> new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(),
            // Increment or set 1 to the counter,
            // and return whether 3 elements are published.
            (map, num) -> map.merge(num, 1, Integer::sum) <= 3,
            // Clean up the state.
            map -> map.clear());

StepVerifier.create(first3PerMod2).expectNext(9, 3, 7, 4, 10, 6).verifyComplete();
```